# Downcast from AnyObject to UIImage[] - Swift

Tags: uiimage, swift, downcast

I'm trying to convert the results of a valueForKeyPath into an array of UIImages.  When trying to do it I get met with this error

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>     "**TToFC9TableView19TableViewControllers6photosGSqGSaCSo7UIImage**", referenced from:
>         __TFC9TableView29JustPostedTableViewController11fetchPhotosfS0_FT_T_ in JustPostedTableViewController.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Here's my attempt at the code in swift:
The propertyListResults is an NSDictionary, and the parameter in valueForKeyPath is a String

```
var photos : AnyObject = (propertyListResults as AnyObject).valueForKeyPath(flickrFetcher.FLICKR_RESULTS_PHOTOS)

self.photos = photos as? UIImage[]
```

And the working Objective-C version of the code is

```
NSArray *photos = [propertyListResults valueForKeyPath:FLICKR_RESULTS_PHOTOS];
self.photos = photos
```

Comment: Isnt Array of type struct and thus `Any` and not `AnyObject`? => you may have to work with NSArray in Swift

Comment: @ChristianDietrich, swift automatically converts it to NSArray when trying to assign it to an AnyObject. [It does that will all basic value types](http://drewag.me/posts/swift-s-weird-handling-of-basic-value-types-and-anyobject?source=stackoverflow)

Comment: @ChristianDietrich I changed it to `Any` it gives this error `Command /Applications/Xcode6Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift failed with exit code 254`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run swift-demangle on `"__TToFC9TableView19TableViewControllers6photosGSqGSaCSo7UIImage__"` you get:

```
@objc TableView.TableViewController.photos.setter : (ObjectiveC.UIImage[])?
```

That means that the linker is not finding a setter for photos on TableViewController. It seems that you are using a TableViewController instead of your own subclass that has a `photos` property.

Also, `photos as? UIImage[]` returns an Optional because it is possible for it to fail. You should do the following:

```
if let images : [UIImage] = photos as? [UIImage] {
    self.photos = images
}
```

This checks if `photos` can be converted to `[UIImage]`. If it can, it assigns it to `self.photos`

**Edit**: Updated UIImage array syntax to the new array syntax in the beta 3

Comment: I tried, still getting the same error, here's the full log that Xcode shows me http://pastebin.com/Qx8piqNC

Comment: Thanks @drewag, i'm not getting any errors now but it seems its not letting me convert photos the photos as they're not populating the Array.  Going to look over my code and see where I've went wrong

Comment: Got it working @Drewag I managed to get it working bar one detail. I'm getting a `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` on this line of code `cell.detailTextLabel.text = photo.valueForKeyPath(flickerFetcher.FLICKR_PHOTO_DESCRIPTION) as String`  the console tells me it cannot unwrap Optional.None yet the line above it, `cell.textLabel.text = photo.valueForKeyPath(flickerFetcher.FLICKR_PHOTO_TITLE) as String` works successfully

Comment: Figured it out.  I changes the table cell back to just the basic type while I was trying to figure out the initial problem.  All is working now.  Thanks for the help